# Subprocess call is not working in python but the command is working in terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, fasttext

When i run `./fasttext` from terminal it runs well. But when i try it with `subprocess.check_output('./fasttext')` it is giving the error as.

**Error**

```
CalledProcessError                        
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a048dbef034f> in <module>()
      1 from subprocess import check_output
      2 from subprocess import call
----> 3 a1 = check_output('./fasttext')
      4 
      5 #a = check_output('./fasttext print-sentence-vectors ~/Vaiju/Project/all code and data/My Code/TrainedModels/wiki_unigrams.bin < 1fasttext.test.txt')

/home/vaijenath/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    571         if cmd is None:
    572             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 573         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    574     return output
    575 

CalledProcessError: Command './fasttext' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I am in the same directory as fasttext is present in notebook.

Comment: It looks like python is just reporting the non-zero exit status. It looks like you are thinking about using `call` instead. What happens when you try that?

Comment: When I use call it is saying no file or directory. But not getting which file it is.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. The problem is solved by using shell=True argument in call.

Comment: This is literally not believable -- `shell=True` would only resolve the specific problem at hand (of the program being launched being successfully executed but exiting with a nonzero exit status) if your actual `args` value was something different than what you gave in the question.

Comment: If it weren't `'./fasttext'` but `'./fasttext arg1 arg2 ...'`, for instance, *then* the original code would be wrong without either setting `shell=True` (the bad answer), or replacing the string with a list like `['./fasttext', 'arg1', 'arg2']` (the good answer). See the warning in red at https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments for a discussion of why `shell=True` is bad practice.

Comment: (`shell=True` can work around an issue where the program being run is marked executable but doesn't have a valid shebang, but if that were the problem it would be a different error, something like `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error` -- and in that case the right answer is to fix the script to actually be executable without involving a shell).

Answer (score 1):

`check_output` only throws an error if the exit status isn't 0. The command you are trying to run `./fasttext` exits with 1 because you didn't follow the correct usage pattern. In the terminal it gives you some documentation but still exits with 1, if you don't believe me (and you shouldn't ;)) run `./fasttext; echo $?` in the terminal and you'll see the exit status.

So simply use something like:
`a1 = check_output(['./fasttext', 'predict', <model>, <out>])`

Notes :

- Check output returns a byte. You might be interested in `.decode("utf-8")` in order to `.split("\n")`
- Facebook now has a very simple [wrapper](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python) for python

Answer (score 0):

Your real use case should look like this:

```
import subprocess
import os.path

a = subprocess.check_output([
  './fasttext',
  'print-sentence-vectors',
  os.path.expanduser('~/Vaiju/Project/all code and data/My Code/TrainedModels/wiki_unigrams.bin'),
], stdin=open('1fasttext.test.txt', 'r'))
```

Note that each argument is passed as a separate list member; redirections are performed via Python (in this case, using `stdin=` instead of a `<` redirection), and replacing expansions like `~` has to be done by Python (as, here, with `os.path.expanduser()`).